# scanf for both character and integer

Tags: c++, c, format, scanf

I am trying to take input character and integer both. But when i use **cin>>ch>>val;** for taking input,it works.But Using **scanf("%c%d",&ch,&val);**,it shows me run time error.What can i do to get rid of this problem? I want to use scanf for faster input.
Here is my partial code:

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
    int q;
    scanf("%d",&q);
    while(q--)
    {
        char ch;
        int val,in;
        //cin>>ch>>val;
        scanf("%c %d",&ch,&val);
        in=val;
        if(ch=='a'){
            //scanf("%d",&val);
            //update(1,0,m,++indx,val);
            printf("First Case\n");
        }else{
            //si(in);
            //if(in>tree[1]) printf("none\n");
            //else query(1,0,m,in);
            printf("Second Case\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should this question be tagged `c++`?

Comment: Maybe you need a space: `"%c %d"`.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: What does `scanf` [*return*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value)? And have you tried to catch the crash in a debugger to see where in your code it really happens? Because the code you currently show is perfectly fine by itself. Perhaps the problem is related to something else? Without a [mcve] it's really impossible to say anything more.

Comment: scanf() is working perfectly all right... Can you show us the full code and share the error too

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). "It doesn't work" is not a suitable description. Please [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: @FiddlingBits is your space in the wrong place? `%d` filters leading whitespace but `%c` does not, so I would use `" %c%d"` with a space before `%c`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Are you asking rhetorically?  I use `printf` so little, I'm not sure.

Comment: @FiddlingBits not rhetorical. There is never a *need* for a space before `%d` or `%s` or `%f` but there *can be* a need for one before `%c` or `%[]`, because those do not automatically filter leading whitespace.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks a lot..It works perfectly .. I'v used  " %c%d"

Comment: @AlaminKawsar you also **must** check the return value from `scanf` functions – the number of items converted. And please don't correct code posted here: correct the code on your own machine, and leave this question so that comments make sense to others who read it.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ok..It shows 2 iteam. Thank you so much.

Comment: Required reading:  [Disadvantages of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf)

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you should be using the safer `cin` and `cout`.  Also, use `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code! It works fine for me. So probably you're using scanf in C++ and forgot to include or maybe it's something else with your code. 
Can you share the full code. There is no issue with scanf() function as you have mentioned. You can take multiple inputs like scanf(%d%d%c%c,&a,&b,&c,&d);

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    int q=1;
    while(q--)
    {
        char ch;
        int val,in;
        scanf("%c%d",&ch,&val);
        in=val;
        if(ch=='a'){
            printf("%d",val);
        }else{
            printf("%d",val);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But you should check return value from scanf("%c%d",&ch,&val);
I think your code will return 1.But it should return 2

Comment: Sorry..I use scanf for taking q(variable) value.That makes the problem.Your given code is perfect